# Word that expresses the state of being finite or infinite without specifying which one it is

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm looking for a word similar to saying, "It could be black or grey or green, regardless of **colour** it still holds ....."

I want to say

> It could be finite or infinite,
>   regardless of ***<the word I'm looking for>*** it still holds....

If you need more clarity I'll reply within the minute; so please ask.

Comment: size/scope/scale/extent don't work?

Comment: Perhaps "temporality."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word *cardinality* is used to describe the number of members of a set.  Cardinal numbers can be both finite and infinite.  For example, 1, 2, and 3 are finite cardinal numbers.  Infinite cardinal numbers are denoted by the Hebrew letter aleph together with a subscript.

> it could be finite or infinite, regardless of cardinality it still holds...

See [wikipedia entry for Cardinal Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) for more details.

See also the entry for [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Comment: So Cardinality means, something along the lines of, "gender in terms of finite or infinite" ?

Comment: in other words I mean could I say this specific sentence "Suppose a is a sequence, regardless of cardinality, we define it as..."

Comment: @K.M. Yes, it works well for your second comment.  Cardinality is a measure of size and encompasses both finite and infinite magnitudes.  It works for the example you have given, but it is not simply a finite or infinite distinction, or a "binary" distinction such as gender being male or female (if that's not to politically incorrect).